# can not start python script in crontab on reboot

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

In crontab I have:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /root/mydirectory/mypythonfile.py
```

Using: `which python3` I get:  `/usr/bin/python3`

at the start of the python script I have: `#!/usr/bin/python3`

The python file is executable for everyone.

Running `./mypythonfile.py` in shell works o.k.

I have no idea left what to do, to make this file execute via crontab. I played in crontab and executed some commands (not python script) and it worked fine.

I am logged in as Root, so this should not be a problem as well.

EDIT:
How do I know it's not running?

I created a script, which sends e-mail, inserts dummy data in database and I checked Htop for .py file. Zero on all.

Comment: how do you know it is not running at boot time?

Comment: @balderman In script I have triggers: Send email, insert into database and also checking htop doesn't find any .py running.

Comment: What is the error you get? Is the according filesystem mounted at the time the script is executed? BTW: You can run `python somescript.py` or add a hashbang line (`#!/usr/bin/python`), there's no need for both.

Comment: Do you expect a programming error? Here at Stack Overflow we concentrate on programming, not on system configuration. [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) might be better suited for this question.

Comment: @filtertips try to use a log file (as the first line of the script) and see if a log message is written

Comment: Could you try to modify your crontab as follows: @reboot python3 /root/mydirectory/mypythonfile.py &

Comment: You can find out its process number like this : ps aux | grep /root/mydirectory/mypythonfile.py